# How to make custom DNS servers show up in resolv.conf automatically after prepending DNS servers in Kali Linux?

Tags: networking, kali-linux, resolv.conf, dhclient

I prepended DNS servers in dhclient.conf as such:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222, 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8;
```

I restarted network using:

```
$service network-manager restart
```

So far so good but when I type `$cat /etc/resolv.conf`the DNS I added to dhclient.conf won't show up.

I also tried activating VPN using VPN book `VPN bookvpnbook-us1-udp25000.ovpn` to no avail.

Because, in this case, my internet connection fails if I don't brute-force the DNS addresses into the resolv.conf.